# Android weird object behavior

Tags: android, oop

I have this FacebookUser object i've created:

```
    private String  id,name, status;    
    private double distance = -1, longitude, latitude;
    private transient Drawable profilePicture,gender;
    private boolean isFacebookFriend = false, isApplicationFriend = false, isClicked = false, isOnline = false, isLoaderChecked=false;


    public FacebookUser()
    {

    }

    public FacebookUser(String id, String name) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);     
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        if (isApplicationFriend())
            return name;
        else
            return "";
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isApplicationFriend() {
        return isApplicationFriend;
    }

    public void setApplicationFriend(boolean isApplicationFriend) {
        this.isApplicationFriend = isApplicationFriend;
    }   
}
```

My problem is with the getName() method.

When showing an ArrayList of FacebookUser in a ListView, i'm using FacebookUser.getName() to display the name in a TextView.

Now, i'm 100% sure that isApplicationFriend() return true - and i've even logged it near the TextView text insert.

So why does getName() keep returning "" ??

Comment: If `isApplicationFriend()` is true, then most likely `name` has no value assigned to it

Comment: If isApplicationFriends() is true, and name has no value, then it'd turn null... So probably, your isApplicationFriends() turns false... Did you try to log ?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds "Drawable profilePicture,gender" funny?

Comment: as i've written - i've tried to log it and it is true...

Comment: Try debugging it, for the case where you think the name should be returned (and hence applicationFriend is true). If you're in Eclipse just add a breakpoint and debug it as an Android application either in the emulator or on a real device. This will quickly tell you what's wrong.

Comment: facebookUserHolder.name.setText(facebookUser.getName());
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),facebookUser.getName());
if using only return name with no condition and turns out just fine

Answer (score 0):

You're right you're right... i'm so silly...

The method was called before and emptied the name property...

Sorry...